# How to send additional attribute to assigned method?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

I found in internet such solution as:

```
def is_owner(self):
    if self.request.user.profile_url == self.kwargs['profile_url']:
        return True
    else:
        raise PermissionDenied

class CompanyProfileUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = CompanyProfile
    template_name = 'profiles/create.html'
    fields = ['user', 'name']

    test_func = is_owner
```

Could anyone tell me, how to send additional value to the method?
I want to have something like:

```
def is_owner(self, profile_type):
    if profile_type == 'user':
        if self.request.user.profile_url == self.kwargs['profile_url']:
            return True
        else:
            raise PermissionDenied

    else:
        # some code
```

`test_func = is_owner('user')` obviously is not working because there is no `self`

p.s. `test_func` is a method of `UserPassesTestMixin` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't without making changes to `UserPassesTestMixin`. An easier solution may be to supply a `kwarg` to the view in the urls.py file or create a new subclass of the View with a different `profile_type` property on the class.

For example:

```
class CompanyProfileUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = CompanyProfile
    template_name = 'profiles/create.html'
    fields = ['user', 'name']

    def test_func(self):
        if self.kwargs['profile_type'] == 'user':
            if self.request.user.profile_url == self.kwargs['profile_url']:
                return True
            else:
                raise PermissionDenied
        else:
            # something
            pass

urlpatterns += [
    url('^$', views.CompanyProfileUpdateView.as_view(), name='update_user', kwargs={'profile_type': 'user'}),
    url('^$', views.CompanyProfileUpdateView.as_view(), name='update_other', kwargs={'profile_type': 'other type'})
]
```

Second option:

```
class CompanyProfileUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = CompanyProfile
    template_name = 'profiles/create.html'
    fields = ['user', 'name']

    profile_type = 'user'
    def test_func(self):
        if self.profile_type == 'user':
            if self.request.user.profile_url == self.kwargs['profile_url']:
                return True
            else:
                raise PermissionDenied
        else:
            # something
            pass

class OtherProfileUpdateView(CompanyProfileUpdateView):
    profile_type = 'other type'
```

Comment: The 1st option is acceptable. There are 2 moments hovewer: 1) `def is_owner(self):` must be outside of the class 2) `url('^$', views.CompanyProfileUpdateView.as_view(kwargs={'profile_type': 'user'}), name='update_user'),` does not work. I need to change it to `url('^$', views.CompanyProfileUpdateView.as_view(), kwargs={'profile_type': 'user'}, name='update_user'),` Thanks.

Comment: According to the docs you should simply override `test_func` rather than assign something else to it.

Comment: Yes, I know :) but I have 9 views which check the owner, so want to avoid code repeating and the assigning trick I found in the source of `django-imagestore` - https://github.com/hovel/imagestore/blob/master/imagestore/views.py